# Using kwargs in while loops - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, keyword-argument

In the code below I'm trying to check whether a value (b) is a key in kwargs, and if it is, do the rest of it.

```
def shop(**kwargs):
    buy = 1
    print ("Welcome to the shop!")
    for i, v in kwargs.items():
        print ("    ", i, ": ", v)
    while buy == 1:
        b = input ("What would you like to buy? ").lower()
        if b == i.lower():
            if v <= Player.gold:
                Player.gold -= v
                Player.inv_plus(i)
                print ("You bought ", i, "for ", v, "gold!")
                print ("Your gold: ", Player.gold)
                print (Player.show_inv())
                print ()
            else:
                print ("You don't have enough gold!")
                print ()
        elif b == "exit":
            buy = 0
        else:
            print ("We don't sell that item!")
            print ()

shop(Stone=5, Potion=10)
```

However, when I try and run the code, it always allows just one option. I'm finding that difficult to explain so I'll give an example:

```
Welcome to the shop!
     Stone :  5
     Potion :  10
What would you like to buy? stone
We don't sell that item!

What would you like to buy? potion
You bought  Potion for  10 gold!
Your gold:  0
Inventory: 
     Potion 6
     Stone 2
```

It won't accept stone, even though it is in the dictionary, however, it will accept potion. Other times it will be the other way around.

At first I thought it was because it was in a while loop, but now I'm not so sure, and I can't find anything that can help me with this anywhere else.

Sorry if this is quite specific, but this is giving me quite a bit of trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you loop through all the items to print them:

```
for i, v in kwargs.items():
    print ("    ", i, ": ", v)
```

the `i` variable ends up holding the name of the last item in kwargs.  That's why it works for 'potion' but not for 'stone'.

As Mohammed answered, you need to check all of the items in `kwargs`, not just the last one.

Comment: "the `i` variable ends up holding the name of the last item in kwargs" - where what ends up coming last is completely arbitrary and not necessarily connected to the order of the arguments in the call, alphabetical order, or anything consistent in any way.

Answer (score 0):

This might be better factored into a `try..except` clause:

```
def shop(**kwargs):
    buy = 1
    print ("Welcome to the shop!")
    for i, v in kwargs.items():
        print ("    ", i, ": ", v)
    while True:
        b = input ("What would you like to buy? ").lower()
        if b == 'exit':
            break
        try:
            v = kwargs[b.capitalize()]
        except KeyError:
            print ("We don't sell that item!")
            print ()
            continue
        if v <= Player.gold:
            Player.gold -= v
            Player.inv_plus(i)
            print ("You bought ", b, "for ", v, "gold!")
            print ("Your gold: ", Player.gold)
            print (Player.show_inv())
            print ()
        else:
            print ("You don't have enough gold!")
            print ()
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I don't understand why you're doing v = kwargs[b.capitalize()]? Wouldn't that just change v to b? Either way you get a KeyError every time.

Comment: This line turns the lower case `b`, e.g. `'stone'` into a possible key for the `kwargs` dictionary, i.e. `'Stone'`. If the keys are not like this, you may need some other conversion.